# Q: Bases and Frames using Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Define $w: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb C$ by

\begin{equation}
w(t) =\begin{cases}
    1/\sqrt{2\pi} & t \in [0, 2\pi)\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

and for $n \in \Bbb Z$ and $m \in \Bbb Z$, define $\varphi_{n,m} \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ by $\varphi_{n,m}(t) = w(t-2n\pi)e^{imt}$.

1. Show $\Phi = \{\varphi_{n,m} | n,m \in \Bbb Z\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\Bbb R)$ using standard facts about Fourier Series.
2. Let $\Psi = \varphi_{n,m}(t) = w(t-n\pi)e^{imt}$.  Show $\Psi$ is not a basis in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ by giving two distinct expansions for the zero signal term.
3. Find frame bounds for $\Psi$ and the dual frame for $\tilde{\Psi}$.  Express an arbitrary signal $x \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ in terms of this frame and, in particular, express $w$ as an expansion in $\Psi$.

---

**My Attempt/Input**

The first two parts, I kind of get intuitively but am having a hard time formalizing it.  I am a bit lost on the last part.  I know what the condition of a frame is and that a tight frame is when the bounds A=B but don't know how to show that.